# How can i mock a component async dependency with jest

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, mocking, jestjs

I am testing a react-native component in which imports a dependency (named import and async) which performs some logic and just returns a boolean but i think jest is not waiting for it to finish. which also logs an error.

"Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue."

currently this is the implementation i have tried..

this is the code of the test

```java
// OfflineNotice.test.js

import React from 'react';

import { OfflineNotice } from './OfflineNotice';

jest.mock('../../service/user', () => ({
    __esModule: true,
    checkIfConnectivityIsValid: () => (
        Promise.resolve(true)
    ),
}));

describe('<OfflineNotice/> test suite', () => {
    const mockOnNetworkConnected = jest.fn();

    test('it should render <OfflineNotice/> component', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(
            <OfflineNotice
                onNetworkConnected={mockOnNetworkConnected}
                network={{
                    isConnected: true,
                    connectionType: 'value',
                }}
            />,
        );
        expect(wrapper).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

the code of the component that i was testing

```java
// the dependency i need to mock
import { checkIfConnectivityIsValid } from '../../service/user';

// the implementation is as follows
export class OfflineNotice extends PureComponent {
    componentWillMount() {
        const { network } = this.props;
        const { isConnected, connectionType } = network;
        this.handleConnectivityChange(isConnected, connectionType);
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        const { network } = this.props;
        const { isConnected, connectionType } = network;
        this.handleConnectivityChange(isConnected, connectionType);
    }

    handleConnectivityChange = async (isConnected, connectionType) => {
        const { onNetworkConnected } = this.props;

        // how the service was used only returns boolean
        const isValid = await checkIfConnectivityIsValid(connectionType);

        let status = null;
        let message = null;

        if (isConnected && isValid) {
            status = 'online';
            message = string.NETWORK_MESSAGE.AVAILABLE;
            this.fadeOut();
            onNetworkConnected();
        } else if (isConnected) {
            status = 'invalid';
            message = string.NETWORK_MESSAGE.INVALID;
            this.containerOpacity.setValue(1);
        } else {
            status = 'offline';
            message = string.NETWORK_MESSAGE.NO_INTERNET;
            this.containerOpacity.setValue(1);
        }

        this.setState({ status, message });
    };
```

then running the test is able to render the component. though on code coverage the code stops on the "const isValid = await checkIfConnectivityIsValid(connectionType);" part in which it says that the statement onward is not covered.

Comment: What version of jest are you using ?

Comment: Besides, can you test it without adding any side effect in componentWillMount ? It really should work

Comment: I'm having a hard time recreating the issue, can you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @jgoday i am using the latest version of jest which is 24.1

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors yeah i already removed some part of the code which doesnt seem to be part of the problem..